# Remove tag name but retain its value

Tags: c#

I need to remove the tag name but retain its value or its content. I am able to remove its tag but this also removes its content or value.

But I only need to remove its tag name and its attribute, and retain its content. How can Ido this?

Here is the sample xml file:

```
<i><RefSource>1</RefSource></i>
<i><RefSource value="1">3</RefSource></i>
```

The desired output:

```
<i>1</i>
<i>3</i>
```

Another part of xml file. because the xml file has a different tag.
 `<Somename> <OrgDivision>Ask question</OrgDivision> <OrgName>Ask question organization</OrgName> <OrgAddress> <City>a</City> <State>b</State> <Country>c</Country> </OrgAddress> </Somename>`

what i want is remove the OrgAddress

possible output

```
<Somename> <OrgDivision>Ask question</OrgDivision> <OrgName>Ask question organization</OrgName>  <City>a</City> <State>b</State> <Country>c</Country>  </Somename>
```

Another question.

I have to check a tag name and its attribute

```
<Emphasis Type="Italic">n</Emphasis>
```

If I found a Emphasis tag name with Type="Italic" attribute. Change its tag name to I

the desired output is

```
<i>n<i>
```

code tried for removing tag name

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xmlfile.xml");


                    doc.Descendants("RefSource")
                        .Remove();
```

but it removes also the value. i only need to remove the tag name

Comment: What would you want to happen if it contained multiple child elements, or if there were sibling text nodes? e.g. `<i>a<RefSource>1<x>2</x>3<y>4</y>5</RefSource>b</i>`

Comment: "Another question." -- one question per question please.

Comment: wow. sir jon skeet. the output is <i>a1<x>2</x>3<y>4</y>5b</i>

so far i didn't have a tag that look like that sir.

Comment: sorry about that. i didn't know. i thought its a good idea. since they are almost similar question. sorry about that. next time. ill create a thread per question

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows the code you've got so far, along with an explanation of what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble getting to work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho sir. i already updated my question. sorry for not posting the code i tried. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xmlfile.xml");

// Remove RefSource tags.
foreach (var node in doc.Descendants("RefSource").ToList())
{
    node.ReplaceWith(node.Value);
}

// Remove OrgAddress tags.
foreach (var node in doc.Root.Descendants().ToList())
{
    if (node.HasElements)
    {
        node.ReplaceWith(node.Elements());
    }
}

// Change Emphasis tags to i tags.
foreach (var node in doc.Descendants("Emphasis").ToList())
{
    node.ReplaceWith(new XElement("i", node.Value));
}

doc.Save("xmlfile2.xml");
```

Comment: it doesn't work. example xml 

   <Somename>
              <OrgDivision>Ask question</OrgDivision>
              <OrgName>Ask question organization</OrgName>
              <OrgAddress>
                <City>a</City>
                <State>b</State>
                <Country>c</Country>
              </OrgAddress>
            </Somename>

code used 
foreach (var node in doc.Descendants("OrgAddress").ToList())
{
    node.Parent.ReplaceAll(node.Value);
    // or
    //node.ReplaceWith(node.Value);
}
output <Somename>abc</Somename>

what i want sir is remove only the tag name

Comment: @askquestionzero - Why in the question you shown a xml but answer code is used to quite a different xml?

Comment: sorry about that sir. but the problem is still the same.

Comment: @askquestionzero - you should edit the question, show real xml input.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using Regular Expressions? An XML file is a text based file. You can do the desired replacement using Regex Replace.
For example,

Regex -

`(?is)</?RefSource.*?>`

Replacement String - [Empty]

Target String -

`<i><RefSource>1</RefSource></i>`

`<i><RefSource value="1">3</RefSource></i>`

You can try it here http://regexhero.net/tester/

After this replacement you can use that file with XMLDocument.